# Checking if function exist in same scope when supplied the function name

Tags: javascript, function

I've got this `format` prototype method (simplified) and what I wanna do is check if char is alphabetic (case insensitive), **and** if it's also a function declared in the **same scope**. If it is, I want to call the function. So if I pass in `x` it should execute the alert.

I'm gonna be using this method to format a date by the given format string. E.g. `format('H:i:s')` it would check if H, i, and s is a function and call them.

How can achieve that?

I tried something based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/359910/1115367

Here's my code:

```
function Time() {
    //initialization
}

Time.prototype = {
    format: function (char) {
        if (char.test(/[a-z]/i) && typeof window[char] === 'function') { //undefined
           window[char]();
        }

        function x() {
            alert('works');
        }
    }
};
```

If I pass in a value it returns: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: so does your code not work? what doesn't it do?

Comment: It gives me an error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Comment: what line is the error generated on? if `window[char]` is not a function then it wouldnt get called at `window[char]();`

Comment: What object type are you trying to add this to the prototype of? By the way, your example is simply replacing the prototype of your `testObject`, instead of adding your `format` function to the existing prototype.

Comment: This *is* the prototype, not a replacement.

Comment: So, why does this need to be added to an existing object, instead of creating a new object like I show in my answer? I'm just trying to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @forgivenson Because it is related to my `Time` object, and I would like it in the prototype and not the constructor itself.

Comment: You might benefit from reading https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures .

Comment: Well, you can just set the prototype of your `Time` class: `Time.prototype = {  format: //.... etc };`. Just use `this` instead of `window`, like I did in my answer. But I'm not really sure what that gains you over just adding them as part of the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

`test()` is not a function of strings, it is a function of `RegExp`. See the documentation for `test` here: [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

So, create a `RegExp` object first, then use it to call `test`, passing in your string, `char`.

After looking at your code more, I think you need to turn turn your format function into a 'class' (JavaScript doesn't really have classes, but you can create an object from a function).

```
function Formatter() {
    this.format = function(char) {
        var regex = /[a-z]/i;

        if (regex.test(char) && typeof this[char] === 'function') {
           this[char]();
        }
    };

    this.x = function() {
        alert('works');
    }
}

var formatter = new Formatter();

formatter.format('x');
```

And here is the working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2xz1ce7/1).

As you can see, you create a formatter object, which contains the `format` function and your `x` function in its scope, `this`.

Comment: Ah, I see. But if I pass in `x` as an argument, it should alert `works`, it doesn't.

Comment: That's more what I'm looking for. So there is no way I can use it in a prototype method?

Comment: I didn't know you changed your question, so I didn't know you wanted to do that. Let me take a look.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I could explain it a little better.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to retrieve a local variables (or function) by name (as far as I know anyway).

Declared named functions are assigned to a variable of the same name: `function thing(){}` ~ `var thing = function(){}`

Global variables are automatically attached to `window` so you can retrieve them by name using the `window` object.

However, that is (fortunately) not the case for all other variables.

For example

```js
var global1 = 'thing'; // root level (no wrapping function) -> global

(function(){
    global2 = 'global';     // no 'var' keyword -> global variable (bad practice and not accepted in strict mode)
    var local = 'whatever'; // local variable

    function check(name){
        if(window[name]) console.log('found: '+ name);
        else console.log('nope: '+name);
    }

    check('foo');
    check('global1');
    check('global2');
    check('local');
}());
```

will output:

```
[Log] nope: foo
[Log] found: global1
[Log] found: global2
[Log] nope: local
```

What you can do however is to attach your methods to an object.

**Edit**

If it is an option, you can also directly pass the function as argument (instead of a string containing its name).

```js
function a(){}

function toCall(f){
   // do stuff with f
}

toCall(a);
```

Comment: Well, I actually don't want to call a global function but the one that's in the same scope of the method, called `x()` if I pass in `x` as an argument.

Comment: But I'm afraid you can't do that.

Comment: What you can do however is to pass the function itself as argument (and not its name in a string).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) to create your scope:

```
var Time = (function() {
  var handlers = {
    x: function () {
      console.log('x invoked');
    }
  };

  function Time() {
    // fun stuff
  }

  Time.prototype = {
    format: function(char) {
      handlers[char](); // if char === 'x'
    }
  };

  return Time;
}());
```